# Edit questions tags in the question view

Tags: feature-request, tags, question-lists

Quite frequently it is apparent that a question misses an important tag only from its title. For instance it is not rare that I see a question of the sort "*How to sum array elements in C++"* that only has `array` and `sum` as tags.

I think it would be convenient if it is possible to edit a question's tags from the questions view(of course if you gained the privilege). There only question's title and the first few lines are displayed, but one can see a lot of questions at the same time. I think if this feature is used responsibly it can save several clicks for editing the tags of questions that apparently miss an important and relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

The title and the first few lines might be enough data to realise a language tag is missing, but it isn't enough for you to determine all the tag changes that are necessary. It *certainly* isn't enough information to make an informed, complete edit of a question.

I'm against anything the encourages half-edits, include this feature I'm afraid.

Comment: That is why I say `I think if this feature is used responsibly` After all if you gained the privilege you are supposed to be responsible right?

Comment: @izomorphius But why should someone do a minor edit when they could improve multiple problems in a question in a single edit? This feature encourages people to just to half a job (or less).

Comment: Adding a language tag for instance usually has a huge impact. The question will reach the most appropriate audience and the probability to get an answer increases greatly.

Comment: +1 @Duncan totally agree with you and youve got valid points and args

Comment: It's not necessarily laziness: I might be able to recognize that an SO question is about PHP without having the competence or time to do a full edit. Adding a major tag (such as a programming language tag on SO) ensures at least that the right people will see the question. Your remark about CW is wrong — only body edits count.

Comment: @Gilles Thank you for the clarification, I mistakenly thought all edits contributed to the CW issue. And perhaps the usage of the word "lazy" was a bit emotive, but I remain unconvinced this feature is a great idea. I've removed that particular comment.